# Flutter:How to convert Cards UI or View to Individual View Please find the HomeScreen Page code and try to convert to detailed individual view

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, data-retrieval

```
Flutter:How to convert Cards UI or View to Individual View Please find the HomeScreen Page code and try to convert to detailed individual view

                                            import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/ListTiles.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/main.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:gadjet_inventory/Form/Data.dart';

import 'UploadData.dart';

import 'package:pdf_flutter/pdf_flutter.dart';
// ignore: must_be_immutable




class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {




  List<Data> dataList = [];
  List<bool> favList = [];
  bool searchState = false;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 



  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    DatabaseReference referenceData = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Data");
    referenceData.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
      dataList.clear();
      favList.clear();

      var keys = dataSnapShot.value.keys;
      var values = dataSnapShot.value;

      for (var key in keys) {

        Data data = new Data(
            values [key]['imgUrl'],
     
            values [key]['wcpdfUrl'],
            values [key]['ugpdfUrl'],
            values [key]['cattegorrytype'],
            values [key]['companyname'],
            values [key]['modelname'],
            values [key]['seriesname'],
            values [key]['year'],
     
            key
          //key is the uploadid
        );
        dataList.add(data);
        auth.currentUser().then((value) {
          DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Data").child(key).child("Fav")
              .child(value.uid).child("state");
          reference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapShot){
            if(snapShot.value!=null){
              if(snapShot.value=="true"){
                favList.add(true);
              }else{
                favList.add(false);
              }
            }else{
              favList.add(false);
            }
          });
        });

      }


      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
        setState(() {
          //
        });
      });


    });


  }

  int selectedRadioTile;

  String get path => null;

  String get title => null;

  setSelectedRadioTile(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadioTile = val;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      //Color(0xffffffff),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: new Text("Device Details", style:
        TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.center),

        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, size: 36, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              //debugPrint("Add New Device Cattegorry");
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return ListTiles();
              }
              )
              ); //
            },
          ),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 36, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: () {
              //debugPrint("Add New Device Cattegorry");
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return MyHomePage();
              }
              )
              ); //
            },
          )
        ],),

      body: dataList.length == 0
          ? Center(
          child: Text("No Data Available", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),))
          : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dataList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return CardUI(dataList[index].imgUrl,dataList[index].wcpdfUrl, dataList[index].cattegorrytype,
                dataList[index].companyname, dataList[index].modelname,dataList[index].seriesname,dataList[index].year,
                dataList[index].uploadid,index);
          }
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget CardUI(String imgUrl, String wcpdfUrl,String cattegorrytype, String companyname, String modelname,
      String seriesname, String year ,
      String uploadId,int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 7,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      //color: Color(0xffff2fc3),
      color:Colors.blueGrey,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.5),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              imgUrl != null
                  ? imgUrl
                  : '',
              width: 500,
              height: 500,

            ),


            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                         child: Text(  "Cattegorry Type:- "
                             "$cattegorrytype",

                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                         ),
                 ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                    child: Text(  "Company Name:- "
                        "$companyname",

                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

               Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                      child: Text(  "Model Name:- "
                          "$modelname",

                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                     ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                      child: Text(  "Series Name:- "
                          "$seriesname",


                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),



              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),

                      child: Text(  "Year Of MFG:- "
                          "$year",

                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),


                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

         

            RaisedButton(


              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),

              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Warranty Card",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),),
            ),
            RadioListTile(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
              title: Text("PDF"),
              //subtitle: Text("Upload PDF File"),
              /*  onChanged: (val) {
                        filePicker(context);
                      },*/
              activeColor: Colors.red,


            ),

            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),

          //  _buildPDF1Field(context),



            PDF.network(
              wcpdfUrl != null
                  ? wcpdfUrl
                  : '',

              width: 600,
              height: 1000,     placeHolder: Image.asset("assets/images/pdf.png",
                height: 600, width: 500),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have uploaded few text items one imageUrl and one  pdf document to firebase storage and able to retrieve them in HomeScreen View (card UI or View (cards list) and List Tile  View( with one image and one text, when tapped on it should show each individual view).

Please guide me How to convert to Individual Retrieving page instead of group of vertical cards list.

Comment: Anybody who is trying to fix my issue. please let me know if you have any further queries

Comment: Anyone still trying to fix my issue. Please et me know if you have any queries still?

Comment: Hi,


        How to convert List Tiles View to Individual List View in flutter.

I have already  retrieved the text items , images and pdfs in vertical card List View or Ui and  also List Tiles View. But Now I want  to show individual List view (DetailsPage when clicked on any item in the List Tiles View.


Please help Urgent.


Thanks